# SVG 'getBBox' fails in a jQueryUI tab

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, svg

I have a stand-alone SVG chart generator that works with all the major browsers. However, I've just added code to display the charts inside a jQuery UI tab, and the code has broken. Specifically, 'getBBox' now generally fails. It throws an exception in FF, works as expected in Opera, and gives the wrong answer in Chrome and Safari.

The difference between the old and new code is only, I think, in my understanding of what a 'document' is inside a tab. In the old stand-alone code, I could display a rectangle and get it's bbox as follows (in all browsers):

```
var svgDocument;
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
...
if(window.svgDocument == null)
   svgDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
...
var lbox = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "x",                50);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "y",                50);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "width",            40);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "height",           40);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke",           "#E810D6");
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width",     2);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity",     1);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-opacity",   1);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", 0);
svgDocument.documentElement.appendChild(lbox);     // displays the box
var bbox = lbox.getBBox();                         // gets the box bounds
```

The problem is that, when I try to display inside a tab, it's not obvious what `svgDocument` should be. This is my current code:

```
var svgDocument = document;
var svgNS       = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgRoot;
...
// handle jQuery UI tabs as follows:
var top, svg, chart;
top   = $(ui.panel).get(0);
svg   = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
chart = "chart" + "-" + ui.panel.id;
svg.setAttributeNS(null, "id", chart);
top.appendChild(svg);
svgRoot = svgDocument.getElementById(chart);
...
// SVG draw is identical, except that svgDocument.documentElement is now svgRoot:
var lbox = svgDocument.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "x",                50);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "y",                50);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "width",            40);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "height",           40);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke",           "#E810D6");
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width",     2);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "fill-opacity",     1);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-opacity",   1);
lbox.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-dasharray", 0);
svgRoot.appendChild(lbox);
var bbox = lbox.getBBox();
```

The new code works "correctly" in Opera. FF, Chrome, and Safari display the rectangle correctly in the new tab, but get the bbox calculation wrong.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

[this is probably the same issue as [Doing Ajax updates in SVG breaks getBBox, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390065/doing-ajax-updates-in-svg-breaks-getbbox-is-there-a-workaround), but there were no answers on that].

### EDIT

I failed to mention that I'm rendering into a hidden tab, which is only displayed when the chart completes. Googling the FF exception code (in the comment below) indicates that there's some issue with getBBox when the element is not displayed. However, I don't understand this. I routinely use getBBox with visibility:hidden to size complex elements before displaying them, on all browsers (when I'm not using tabs). Besides, the rectangle in the example does actually render, as I can see it when the tab becomes visible, so shouldn't getBBox should also work?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), which does a great job of encapsulaing SVG cross-browser (even IE through fallback to VML)?

Comment: Raphael isn't a chart library, and gRaphael is too limited for real-world use. I can't find any useful documentation, though, so I may be wrong. I looked at maybe 20 chart libraries before deciding to write my own code. Highcharts was probably top of the list, and Raphael wasn't even close. The "cross-browser" claim is over-rated. My own vanilla SVG/JS code runs on IE9, FF, Chrome, Opera, and Safari. If someone wants to use IE6-8 then they'll need to download a plugin, or a modern browser.

Comment: what exception does Firefox throw?

Comment: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMSVGLocatable.getBBox] - I've added an edit above.

Comment: @user785194, I know that Raphaël isn't a charting lib, but handcrafted SVG code isn't either. My point was merely that Raphaël may have fixes for some issues related to SVG or specific implementations. But seeing your answer the direct cause wasn't SVG anyways, so nevermind. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Fixed - the answer is actually in the tabs documentation. Whoops.

From http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F

Any component that requires some dimensional computation for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel itself is hidden via display: none so that any elements inside won't report their actual width and height (0 in most browsers).

There's an easy workaround. Use the off-left technique for hiding inactive tab panels. E.g. in your style sheet replace the rule for the class selector ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide" with

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

Comment: I fall into same issue. This issue come from https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=612118
*SVGLocatable.getBBox() fails unless the SVG element it is applied to is attached and rendered*

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390065/doing-ajax-updates-in-svg-breaks-getbbox-is-there-a-workaround/